# Overriding Angular DomElementSchemaRegistry using @ngtools/webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-aot, ngtools

My end goal is to start using a web component library, but also with the preferred outcome of **not** disabling component validation using `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` since this is an important and valuable feature of Angular. There is an issue logged within the Angular repo about making this a supported feature given that web components are now a common browser feature:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12045

However, without there being an Angular supported solution, an alternative method is needed. There are various blog post which talk through this in detail, but there seems to be a difference between how the `DomElementSchemaRegistry` abstract class is initialised depending on whether the JIT compiler is used or whether AOT is used. When AOT is used, `DomElementSchemaRegistry` is initialised explicitly which disallows overriding via the standard providers array.

It appears the method to work around this is to create a new implementation of the `ng` class, which first of all replaces the standard implementation of  `DomElementSchemaRegistry` before running the standard `ng` class code. See here under "AOT Compiler version" heading:
https://indepth.dev/posts/1121/getting-inside-angulars-element-schema-registry-mechanism

I have no doubt this would work fine using a standard Angular installation, but can anyone advise how this might be possible using the `@ngtools/webpack` webpack plugin? Unfortunately, webpack is an important part of our build and cannot currently be replaced.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack